# Is it possible to pass a structure variable as a function argument without previously defining it?

Tags: c, structure, compound-literals

I have two structs defined as so (in `color.h`):

```
typedef struct rgb {
  uint8_t r, g, b;
} rgb;

typedef struct hsv {
  float h, s, v;
} hsv;

hsv rgb2hsv(rgb color);
rgb hsv2rgb(hsv color);
```

I then have the following in `main.c` which works:

```
hsv hsvCol = {i/255.0, 1, 1};
rgb col = hsv2rgb(hsvCol);
```

I want to be able to just create the variable `hsvCol` inside the parameters for `hsv2rgb` without having to create the variable and passing it as a parameter.

I've tried the each of the following (in place of the two lines above), sadly none of which compile :(

```
rgb col = hsv2rgb({i/255.0, 1, 1});
rgb col = hsv2rgb(hsv {i/255.0, 1, 1});
rgb col = hsv2rgb(hsv hsvCol {i/255.0, 1, 1})
rgb col = hsv2rgb(struct hsv {i/255.0, 1, 1});
```

My question is:

1. Can I do what I was trying to do at all (but obviously in a different way)?
2. If 1, how do I go about doing so?

Comment: `rgb col = hsv2rgb((hsv){i/255.0, 1, 1});`

Comment: Aw maaan, that was so simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of a [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.5, paragraph 3,

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace enclosed
>   list of initializers is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list.

and, paragraph 5,

> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the
>   initializer list. [...]

So, in your case, the code like

```
hsv hsvCol = {i/255.0, 1, 1};
rgb col = hsv2rgb(hsvCol);
```

can be re-written as

```
rgb col = hsv2rgb( ( hsv ) {i/255.0, 1, 1} );
                    ^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    |             |
                    |              -- brace enclosed list of initializers
                    -- parenthesized type name
```